# Break statement in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, vb.net-2010

How to break this statement, if this condition is meet ?

```
Val(DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(7).Value) <= 2
```

then after the above statement is meet, it should continue with this statement

```
DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(7 + 1).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(7).Value
```

Here my full code :

```
    Try

        For x As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

            'Strategy 1
            If Val(DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(7).Value) <= 2 Then

                DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(7 + 1).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(7).Value - 2

            Else
                DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(7 + 1).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(7).Value

            End If


        Next


    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say BREAK? Do you mean you want to exit the loop? Do you mean you want stop execution? What happens if more than a single row has a value less than 2 in Col 7? Clarify what you mean by break please... With your code above, it will do as you wish and then move on to the next row until all rows have been processed...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exit the loop after some job you can use [Exit Statement (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2at9t47.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Because you need loop all rows anyway -
use boolean variable to mark that needed value is found already

```vb
Try

    Dim valueFound As Boolean = False
    For x As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        If Val(DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(7).Value) <= 2 Then
            If valueFound = False Then
                DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(7 + 1).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(7).Value - 2
                valueFound = True
            Else
                DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(7 + 1).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(7).Value
            End If
        Else
            'Do something if value is not <= 2
        End If
    Next

Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```